# Java has FindBugs. What is equivalent for Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, static, analysis, findbugs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic code quality tool for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313/automatic-code-quality-tool-for-ruby)

Java has FindBugs™. What is equivalent for Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic code quality tool for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313/automatic-code-quality-tool-for-ruby) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286564/can-anyone-recommend-a-ruby-source-code-analyzer-something-like-pylint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog](http://devver.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/ruby-code-quality-tools/). It talks about different tools (Roodi, Dust and Flog).